# How to define an intermittent subset in GAMS?

Tags: subset

I am building up an optimization model in GAMS for an onsite generation system. I am facing problems in defining intermittent subsets.

The optimization period is over 8 hours from 9AM to 5PM. My model is for 1 year i.e, 8760 hours. I have created one set j such that j=/j1*j8760/. Now I want to creat a subset of j(j1) such that it involves certain time periods over a day,9AM to 5PM.

What I did is I tried to define the subset manually such as for two days I wrote,

j  'Total time'     /j1*j48/

j1(j) 'Optimizaton Period' /j9 * j17, j33 * j41/.

Since I have huge horly data say 8760 hours,I wanted to know how to define this subset using code instead of manually defining them.